# pandas column astype error: TypeError: Cannot cast Index to dtype datetime64[D]

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `pandas` to read a csv file, where the column name is date time like `2017-01-02`. I try to change column type to `datatime64[D]` using following codes:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

However, it raises cast error: `TypeError: Cannot cast Index to dtype datetime64[D]`'

When I change the code to

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype('datetime')
```

It won't raise any errors. Then how should I do to change columns type to `datetime64[D]` or `M8[D]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas methods [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).floor('D')
```

Your solution should working (tested in pandas 0.24.2):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['2015-02-02 12:20:31','2018-01-01 15:32:04'])
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2015-02-02 12:20:31, 2018-01-01 15:32:04]
Index: []

df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).floor('D')
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2015-02-02 00:00:00, 2018-01-01 00:00:00]
Index: []
```